# Azure CICD for SQL Server database deployment using DbUp library

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dbup

I am trying to deploy the database changes through Azure CICD using the DbUp library. But I don't really understand what are the steps to be followed are, and how to start off initially.

Can somebody share how we can deploy the SQL Server database changes using DbUp?

Comment: DbUp is a (great and very useful!) **library** - but not really a framework ... (.NET is a framework)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [extension - DbUp Migration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johanclasson.UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp)

All what you need then it provide:

- connection string
- folder where you keep you script files
- schema
- table name where you are going to keep history

```
- task: UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp@2
  inputs:
    ConnectionString: 'Server=$(DbUp.Server);Database=$(DbUp.Database);User ID=$(DbUp.UserId);Password=$(DbUp.Password);Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;'
    ScriptPath: 'scripts'
    JournalSchemaName: 'dbo'
    JournalTableName: '_SchemaVersions'
```